# How do I devise a python trading algorithm that identifies pivot highs and lows to inform breakout points?

Tags: python, algorithm, indexing, trading

I want to create an algorithm, which will help me point the breakout points in the trading and devise my strategy accordingly.

My code:

```
import pandas as pd
import pandas_ta as ta
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from statistics import variance

# Load your price data into a pandas DataFrame
data = pd.read_csv('data.csv')
close = data['close']
high = data['high']
low = data['low']

def find_pivot_highs(data, length):
    pivot_highs = []
    for i in range(length, len(data) - length):
        if (
            data[i] > max(data[i - length : i])
            and data[i] > max(data[i + 1 : i + length + 1])
        ):
            pivot_highs.append(i)
    return pivot_highs


def find_pivot_lows(data, length):
    pivot_lows = []
    for i in range(length, len(data) - length):
        if (
            data[i] < min(data[i - length : i])
            and data[i] < min(data[i + 1 : i + length + 1])
        ):
            pivot_lows.append(i)
    return pivot_lows

length = 14
k = 1.0
#method = 'Atr'
show = False
n = range(len(close))

# Calculate the indicators using pandas-ta
data['atr'] = ta.atr(high, low, close, length)
data['stddev'] = ta.stdev(close, length)
data['sma1'] = ta.sma(close, length)
data['sma2'] = ta.sma(close * n, length)
data['var'] = variance(close)
data['n'] = data.index

data['slope'] = 0.0
#data['slope'] = np.where(method == 'Atr', data['atr'] / length * k,
#                         np.where(method == 'Stdev', data['stddev'] / length * k,
#                                  method == 'Linreg', data['sma1'] - data['sma2'] * data['n'] / data['var'] / 2 * k))

data['slope_atr'] = data['atr'] / length * k
data['slope_stdev'] = data['stddev'] / length * k
data['slope_linereg'] = (data['sma1'] - data['sma2'] * data['n']) / data['var'] / 2 * k

# Find pivot highs and lows
data['ph'] = find_pivot_highs(high, length)
data['pl'] = find_pivot_lows(low, length)

data['slope_ph'] = data['slope_atr'].where(data.index.isin(data['ph'])).ffill()
data['slope_pl'] = data['slope_atr'].where(data.index.isin(data['pl'])).ffill()

data['upper'] = data['ph'].where(data.index.isin(data['ph'])).ffill() - data['slope_ph']
data['lower'] = data['pl'].where(data.index.isin(data['pl'])).ffill() + data['slope_pl']
```

Here, I'm encountering a strange error:

```
File "/Users/dev.barbhaya9gmail.com/Library/CloudStorage/OneDrive-IITKanpur/Beyond/BRAINWorks/Internship/Project #304/strategy (pandas-ta).py", line 60, in <module>
    data['ph'] = find_pivot_highs(high, length)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py", line 3977, in __setitem__
    self._set_item(key, value)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py", line 4171, in _set_item
    value = self._sanitize_column(value)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py", line 4904, in _sanitize_column
    com.require_length_match(value, self.index)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pandas/core/common.py", line 561, in require_length_match
    raise ValueError(
ValueError: Length of values (6) does not match length of index (374)
```

I've been using the same find_pivot_highs function in a different code and it is being called in a same manner, but there is this error which arises in this case, I'm trying to ascertain the reason. Any leads will be very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

```
# Find pivot highs and lows
data['ph'] = np.nan
data['pl'] = np.nan

pivot_highs = find_pivot_highs(high, length)
pivot_lows = find_pivot_lows(low, length)

# assign the value True to the corresponding indices
for i in pivot_highs:
    data.loc[i, 'ph'] = True

for i in pivot_lows:
    data.loc[i, 'pl'] = True

for i, row in data.iterrows():
    if row['ph'] == True:
        data.loc[i, 'ph_linreg_slope'] = (row['sma1'] - row['sma2'] * row['n']) / row['var'] / 2 * k
        data.loc[i, 'ph_stdev_slope'] = row['stddev'] / length * k
        data.loc[i, 'ph_atr_slope'] = row['atr'] / length * k

for i, row in data.iterrows():
    if row['pl'] == True:
        data.loc[i, 'pl_linreg_slope'] = (row['sma1'] - row['sma2'] * row['n']) / row['var'] / 2 * k
        data.loc[i, 'pl_stdev_slope'] = row['stddev'] / length * k
        data.loc[i, 'pl_atr_slope'] = row['atr'] / length * k
```

Comment: can you similarly help with the `upper` and `lower` columns?

Comment: A wall of code without an explanation is not terribly helpful. If you had that then maybe @driver wouldn't need to be spoon fed the remainder of the code.

Answer (score 0):

```
for i, row in data.iterrows():
    if row['pl'] == True:
        data.loc[i, 'lower_linreg'] = row['close']
        data.loc[i, 'lower_stdev'] = row['close']
        data.loc[i, 'lower_atr'] = row['close']
    else:
        data.loc[i, 'lower_linreg'] = data.loc[i-1, 'lower_linreg'] + row['pl_linreg_slope']
        data.loc[i, 'lower_stdev'] = data.loc[i-1, 'lower_stdev'] + row['pl_stdev_slope']
        data.loc[i, 'lower_atr'] = data.loc[i-1, 'lower_atr'] + row['pl_atr_slope']
```

looks likely, but there's an error and it says:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pandas/core/indexes/base.py", line 3803, in get_loc
    return self._engine.get_loc(casted_key)
  File "pandas/_libs/index.pyx", line 138, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc
  File "pandas/_libs/index.pyx", line 165, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc
  File "pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 5745, in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item
  File "pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 5753, in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item
KeyError: 'lower_linreg'

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/dev.barbhaya9gmail.com/Library/CloudStorage/OneDrive-IITKanpur/Beyond/BRAINWorks/Internship/Project #304/strategy (pandas-ta).py", line 89, in <module>
    data.loc[i, 'lower_linreg'] = data.loc[i-1, 'lower_linreg'] + row['pl_linreg_slope']
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pandas/core/indexing.py", line 1066, in __getitem__
    return self.obj._get_value(*key, takeable=self._takeable)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py", line 3914, in _get_value
    series = self._get_item_cache(col)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py", line 4271, in _get_item_cache
    loc = self.columns.get_loc(item)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pandas/core/indexes/base.py", line 3805, in get_loc
    raise KeyError(key) from err
KeyError: 'lower_linreg'
```

Answer (score -1):

The reason for the error in your original code is that the length of these lists of indices (which represent the pivot points) does not match the length of your DataFrame.

To correctly assign these pivot points to the DataFrame, you need to insert these pivot points into your DataFrame at the corresponding indices. Here's how to do that:

```
# initialize new columns with np.nan or any other fill value
data['ph'] = np.nan
data['pl'] = np.nan

pivot_highs = find_pivot_highs(high, length)
pivot_lows = find_pivot_lows(low, length)

# assign the value True to the corresponding indices
for i in pivot_highs:
    data.loc[i, 'ph'] = True

for i in pivot_lows:
    data.loc[i, 'pl'] = True

data['slope_ph'] = data['slope'].where(data['ph'] == True).ffill()
data['slope_pl'] = data['slope'].where(data['pl'] == True).ffill()

data['upper'] = data['ph'].where(data['ph'] == True).ffill() - data['slope_ph']
data['lower'] = data['pl'].where(data['pl'] == True).ffill() + data['slope_pl']
```

This way, your 'ph' and 'pl' columns will be filled with True at the pivot points and NaN (or whatever fill value you used) everywhere else. If you want to use the actual high/low prices at the pivot points instead of True, you could replace True with high[i] and low[i] respectively.

Finally, you may use data`['ph'].fillna(False)` and `data['pl'].fillna(False)` if you'd prefer to work with True/False values instead of True/NaN.

Comment: I tried your method, but the new problem which I now face is that the code immediately after the **ph** and **pl** doesn't work well.

Comment: `data['slope_ph'] = data['slope_atr'].where(data.index.isin(data['ph'])).ffill()
data['slope_pl'] = data['slope_atr'].where(data.index.isin(data['pl'])).ffill()

data['upper'] = data['ph'].where(data.index.isin(data['ph'])).ffill() - data['slope_ph']
data['lower'] = data['pl'].where(data.index.isin(data['pl'])).ffill() + data['slope_pl']` this is the part which is now causing an issue. if you can help me with the same that will be great.

Comment: `data.index.isin()` function expects the input datatype to be an iterable object, such as a list, tuple, or array-like object, containing the values to check for membership in the index. The output datatype of the `data.index.isin()` method in pandas is a boolean pandas Series. Suggestions according to that will be great.

Comment: Of course, it will create a problem, we changed the format of the data.

In your code snippet, you're trying to use the where method with a boolean series that is derived from checking if the DataFrame's index is in the 'ph' and 'pl' columns. But now, as per our modifications, these columns ('ph' and 'pl') contain True at pivot points and np.nan otherwise, instead of the pivot indices themselves.

I updated my answer check again